# Flask-SQLAlchemy raises unknown database error

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a Web application using flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy, I have the following code

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import  SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask

app= Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+mysqldb://root:presario@127.0.0.1/testdb'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

When I run db.create_all() from command line, I get "unknown database 'testdb'" error.

I'm working on Ubuntu but the code above works on my Windows machine.

I've tried adding the port number, removing the python connector but nothing works.
Below is the stack trace

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
 sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1049, "Unknown database 'testdb'") None None
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would suggest that the database 'testdb' does not exist.

SQLAlchemy will not actually create the database for you. You have to connect to an existing database. It will then create all the tables.

Joe

Comment: Thanks! While in the book "Essential SQLAlchemy" there's an example where SQLLite database is created this way (`metadata.create_all()`).

Comment: @Olia_Pavliuk it has been a while since I've use SQLAlchemy. SQLite databases are just files on disk so it's a little different.

Answer (score 5):

You can create DB like this:

```
url = 'mysql://%s:%s@%s' % (USER, PASSWORD, HOST)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url)  # connect to server

create_str = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s ;" % (DATABASE)
engine.execute(create_str)
engine.execute("USE location;")
db.create_all()
db.session.commit()
```